# What is a "wrap around jacket band"?

Tags: manga-production

I have seen this mentioned in some anime reporting. It sounds like an anime forum or a magazine, but strangely I can't find any information on it.

> The wrap-around jacket band on the seventh volume of Sui Ishida's Tokyo Ghoul:re manga announced on Thursday that Ishida's original Tokyo Ghoul manga will get a live-action film. ([source](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2016-06-16/tokyo-ghoul-manga-gets-live-action-film/.103294))

> The wrap-around jacket band on the sixth compiled volume of Kohske's Gangsta. manga is announcing on Wednesday that an anime adaptation has been green-lit. ([source](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2014-07-08/gangsta-action-manga-gets-anime/.76433))

> The news broke to fans on the wrap-around jacket band of the most recent tankobon manga volume released today in Japan. ([source](https://jotaku.net/2019/10/14/dragon-goes-house-hunting-announces-anime-adaptation/))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an [*obi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obi_(publishing)), which is also known as

> a strip of paper looped around a book or other product.

As Wikipedia continues to mention,

> Many books in Japan are supplied with an *obi*, which is normally added outside any [dust jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_jacket). [...]
>
> In English, the term *belly-band* is sometimes used instead.

---

The following image is the *obi* on *Tokyo Ghoul:re* volume 7.

[image]